# Undefined Internal Linkage and Undefined Symbols Error

Tags: c++, xcode

I tried compiling a simple program on Xcode and got the following messages:

`function<anonymous namespace>::Initialize' has internal linkage but is not defined`

`function<anonymous namespace>::HandleBadInput' has internal linkage but is not defined`

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "(anonymous namespace)::Initialize()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "(anonymous namespace)::HandleBadInput()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The header file looks like this:

```
#ifndef WJKErrorHandling
#define WJKErrorHandling

namespace WJKErrorHandling{

    void Initialize(void);
    int HandleBadInput(void);

}

#endif // defined(WJKErrorHandling)
```

the implementation file looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "WJKErrorHandling.h"

namespace WJKErrorHandling{

    void Initialize(void){

        std::cin.exceptions(std::cin.failbit);
    }

    int HandleBadInput(void){

        std::cerr << "Input Error: wrong type?\n";
        std::cin.clear();

        char BadInput[5];
        std::cin >> BadInput;

        return 1;
    }

}
```

and main.cpp looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "WJKErrorHandling.h"


void Prompt (void){

    //Prompts the user to begin entering numbers

    std::cout << "Begin entering numbers: \n";
}

float GetNumber (void){

    std::cout << "Number: \n";
    float Number;
    std::cin >> Number;
    return Number;
    }

std::string GetString (void){

    std::cout << "String: \n";
    std::string String;
    std::cin >> String;
    return String;

}

int main()
{
    Prompt();
    WJKErrorHandling::Initialize();

    int ReturnCode = 0;

    try{

        float Number = GetNumber();
        std::cout << Number;
        std::string String = GetString();
        std::cout << String;

        std::cout << "SUCCESS!!!!\n";

    }
    catch(...){

        ReturnCode = WJKErrorHandling::HandleBadInput();
    }


    return ReturnCode;
}
```

I've tried finding an answer so far, but I haven't understood any of the posts that I've found.  I'm new with C++, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you compiled the source file containing these WJKErrorHandling functions ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your #define Guard is causing name lookup issue.

change to below style should fix the issue:

```
#ifndef WJK_ERROR_HANDLING_H
#define WJK_ERROR_HANDLING_H
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the non-standard but more idiomatic `#pragma once`, according to its [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once) it is supported by all major compilers.

Since many compilers have optimizations to identify include guards, there is no speed advantage between the two. For myself I see the following advantages of `#pragma once`:

- It has only one meaning (whereas defines serve different purposes) and will not clash with other things (e.g. a namespace as in your case).
- It is little to type and simple to remember.
- You cannot have errors due to a typo (`WJKERRORHANDLNG_H`, ups and I is missing), because you started the header as a copy of another and forgot to change the include guard, which gives you rather nasty bughunting sessions.

Answer (score 0):

This turns out to be a bad include guard:

```
#ifndef WJKErrorHandling
#define WJKErrorHandling
```

because you later try to use `WJKErrorHandling` as a namespace, but the macro makes it go away.

Change your include guard to something like:

```
#ifndef WJKERRORHANDLING_H
#define WJKERRORHANDLING_H
```

which is probably more idiomatic and less likely to conflict with something.