# Why does the following method get internal linkage?

Tags: c++, linkage

I'm using `clang-3.6` and compiling a sizeable project. After a massive re-factoring, a small number of seemingly random methods in a few classes cause warnings such as this:

```
warning: function 'namespace::X::do_something' has internal linkage but is not defined [-Wundefined-internal]
```

The same functions also show up as missing in the linker stage.

Here is the anonymized header for one such function definition in `X.hpp`:

```
class X {
    // ...
    void do_something(
            foo::Foo& foo,
            double a
            double b,
            double c,
            uint8_t d,
            const bar::Bar& bar,
            int dw, int dh);
    // ...
}
```

The function is implemented in `X.cpp` as normal. When `Y.cpp` includes `X.hpp` and does `x->do_something`, the warning about internal linkage appears.

**How can a method defined as above have internal linkage?** What are all the circumstances under which a method gets internal linkage?

And seeing as this function, and others, used to compile just fine and have not even been touched during the refactoring, what kind of side effects (include order, type Foo and Bar) can cause a method to switch to internal linkage?

EDIT:

When I do a full source grep of `do_something`, it gives three results:

`X.hpp`: `void do_something(`

`X.cpp`: `void X::do_something(`

`Y.cpp`: `x->do_something(`

I also tried to change the name of `do_something` into a long guaranteed unique name to rule out any possibility of name conflicts.

As far as I can tell, the posted method definition is unquestionably the one being flagged as having internal linkage.

Comment: If you very carefully examine the function signatures of the declaration and definition, are you absolutely certain they're not different?  Some "gotchas" are capitalisation, parameter types and/or qualifiers, function qualifiers, storage classes, calling conventions, or simply forgetting to add the namespace or class name.

Comment: Is the member `public`? Members default to `private` in a `class`.

Comment: I would also add another "gotcha", based on your comment about having never even modified these classes.  That is: header guards.  Do you think you may have inadvertently copy-pasted a header guard into some other file, and it happens to be excluding the correct class declaration from being used?

Comment: Have you somehow gotten this class inside an anonymous namespace? e.g., header-guard/namespace conflict like http://stackoverflow.com/a/13536961/166389

Comment: @paddy: I added some information that I believe covers all your gotchas (they are all about possible confusion with other methods, right?)

Comment: Your greps don't really help us, since you have not included any context - specifically the namespace - in each case.

Comment: @paddy: I think the fact that only 3 occurrences of the given string in the source tree (especially after making the string unique) can rule out possible confusions. Oh well, in any case, I figured out the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was due to one of the types (i.e. `foo:Foo`) being a template type where one of the ***template parameters*** had erroneously gotten internal linkage.

```
template <typename char const* Name> struct Foo{...};

const char constexpr FooBarName[] = "Bar";

using FooBar = Foo<FooBarName>;
```

The presence of FooBar in any argument list or as a return type would give that method internal linkage. Not even `clang-3.8` with `-Weverything` complained about having a template parameter with internal linkage.

The obvious fix was to properly use `extern const char` for the template string parameter.