# Address of a constexpr in a template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, linker

Can someone solve the mystery of why do I get linking errors if I take the address of a variable that should go in a template parameter only if I make the variable `const`, `constexpr` or `static`, but not oherwise?

The piece(s) of code below are part of a larger project, but I extracted the exact same structure:

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
project(fun)
add_library(fun SHARED fun.cpp)
add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main fun)
```

**fun.cpp**

```
#include "fun.h"
BlaaUser testBlaa(int)
{
    return BlaaUser();
}
```

**fun.h**

```
#pragma once 

#include "types.h"

extern BlaaUser testBlaa(int);
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "fun.h"

int main()
{
    auto b = testBlaa(2);
}
```

**types.h**

```
#pragma once

struct P
{
    char n;
};

template<const P* S>
struct Blaa
{
    Blaa() {}
    char blaa{S->n};
};

//constexpr
//static
//const
P p{};  // <-- Here, right now it works. If I uncomment any of the specifiers, I get errors, see below

using BlaaUser = Blaa<&p>;
```

If I add any kind of specifier I get the following errors:

```
Scanning dependencies of target fun
[ 25%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/fun.dir/fun.cpp.o
[ 50%] Linking CXX shared library libfun.so
[ 50%] Built target fun
Scanning dependencies of target main
[ 75%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o
In file included from /home/fld/work/tmpl_test/main.cpp:1:
/home/fld/work/tmpl_test/fun.h:5:17: warning: ‘BlaaUser testBlaa(int)’ used but never defined
    5 | extern BlaaUser testBlaa(int);
      |                 ^~~~~~~~
[100%] Linking CXX executable main
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x12): undefined reference to `testBlaa(int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/main.dir/build.make:104: main] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:97: CMakeFiles/main.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:103: all] Error 2
```

I sort of have the feeling that it has to do with the address of an object (as per the standard: For pointers to objects, the template arguments have to designate the address of a complete object with static storage duration and a linkage (either internal or external) ) but I'm just a bit confused because if everything goes in one file all is ok, the problem comes when it's split up in libraries ...

Does anyone have any explanations?

Comment: @JeJo not really, the constness of the return of the function is not affecting the outcome, now it complains, like: ```/home/fld/work/tmpl_test/fun.h:5:23: warning: ‘const BlaaUser testBlaa(int)’ used but never defined
    5 | extern const BlaaUser testBlaa(int);
``` and still `main.cpp:(.text+0x12): undefined reference to `testBlaa(int)'
`

Comment: cannot reproduce (it doesn't compile without specifier) https://wandbox.org/permlink/xVQwqoig5Yc4ng1k

Comment: (it seems like the permalink has bug and doesn't show all command line option, click clone and it should show all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The additional specifiers (e.g `const`, `constexpr`) makes the template parameter have internal linkage, which subsequently makes `testBlaa(int)` have internal linkage. It works if you do

```
extern const P p{}
```

right? Maybe [Why does the following method get internal linkage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35155551/why-does-the-following-method-get-internal-linkage) is similar?